# "Thankfully" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, adverbios

Would it be correct to say,

> Hoy es llueve, salvos afortunadamente, manana es hace sol.

when trying to say

> Today is rainy, but **thankfully** tomorrow is sunny.

If not, what would I say instead?

Answer (score 4):

> Hoy llueve, pero gracias a Dios mañana hará Sol

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thankfully)

> thankfully [ˈθæŋkfəlɪ] ADV
>   1. (= fortunately) → gracias a Dios, afortunadamente

Thankfully assumes something or someone is responsible for the more positive outcome that deserves a thank you, hence why I think the most accurate translation should include that meaning. You can change *Dios* to *Alá*, *Jehová* or any other deity.

Comment: Thankfully there is no need to include any god in this.  Thankfully can be expressed as "con suerte" o "afortunadamente" o "por fortuna". Please read the help and remember that your answers should add something the previous answers did not expressed.

Comment: @DGaleano _Gracias a Dios_ , while quite explicitly invoquing God, has become a phrase widely used to mean _afortunadamente_ or _por suerte_. Seeing that both _thankfully_ and _Gracias a Dios_ share the past meaning of actually being thankful to God, why not use the latter to translate the former?

Comment: @DGaleano I forgot to add that, while the other answers are completely correct, the one I've provided keeps a possible religious background user1 might have desired for, in example, a christian character in a story. We lack the context for this sentence, so we must provide the closest translation we can achieve.

Comment: You could trace "afortunadamente" to the roman goddess, just as you trace "thankfully" to the christian god. To me, they both sound non strictly religious, while "gracias a dios" hurts my atheist ears!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest:

> Hoy llueve, pero por suerte mañana estará soleado.

---

> *Today is rainy:* **Hoy está lloviendo / Hoy llueve** *present tense.*
>
> *but thankfully:* pero por suerte.
>
> *tomorrow is sunny:* **mañana estará soleado** (since *mañana* is in future tense, the predicate will be too).

Comment: Would it still be correct to say "Hoy llueve, pero por suerte mañana hace sol." because for this class the teacher expects us to use "hace sol" as that is what we learned in class. I think if I put down sera soleado, she would count it wrong because it isn't what we learned.

Comment: Since the weather "sunny" is in future, the adequate translation of above, i edit my answer for your concern, but before, can you add more info about where you get the translation used in your question? because, as native spanish speaker, the translation that i suggested is a correct one.
You can also wait for other users who can help you better.

Comment: We learned, in spanish class, all the types of weather (Hace calor, hace frio, etc.) And how to say them (Hoy es llueve, manana es llueve) And, if it is any help, my teacher is from the Caribbean, so she might teach different slightly different Spanish than your native language. I just kind of pieced together what I knew and thought "Today is rainy: hoy es llueves" And wrote that down, piece by piece until that sentence was formed.

Comment: @user6818 you can say *hoy llueve, pero por suerte mañana hace sol*, although it's not the most natural construction.  If you've done *ir + a* constructions, you could say *mañana va a hacer sol* which would sound better.  Mauricio: normalmente los alumnnos aprenden el presente simple un tiempo después aprenden el aspecto progresivo y mucho después el futuro simple/sintético (prefiriendo en su vez el futuro implícito usando el presente más un adverbio que marca el futuro)

Comment: @user6818 _Hoy es llueve_ isn't correct, the (es) in the sentence is ommited in the translation, so, you can use **Hoy llueve**.

Comment: @guifa Ahora entiendo, gracias por explicarme a mí también, y espero se le pueda dar una respuesta mas acorde al nivel educativo del OP _ya que realmente no puedo explicar muy bien la formación de la oración mejor de lo que intento hacerlo en la respuesta_.

Answer (score 1):

I'll split the answer to explain a few things:

A) "rainy" is an adjective, but "llueve" is a form of the verb "llover". To keep things simple, in Spanish we would say...

> "today (it is) raining" = "hoy llueve"

In the future you'll learn how to turn "llueve" in it's adjective, "lluvioso", and other ways to express those concepts, but for your exercise that's enough.

B) "salvo" comes from the verb "salvar", and shares it's root with the words "salvation" and "save". We use it to add an exception to something (to *protect* it from the previous affirmation) in the same way English use the word "unless".

> "tomorrow I'll go to school **unless** it's raining" = "mañana iré a la escuela **salvo que** esté lloviendo"

But what you want to express it's not an exception, it's an objection, so you use "pero", the Spanish "but"...

> "but thankfully" = "pero afortunadamente"

C) same as A, "es" it's the verb "to be"  used for adjectives, but "hace" is also a verb. You have plenty of options here too, but let's keep it simple...

> "tomorrow it's sunny" = "mañana hará sol"

"hará" is future for "hace", id you think your teacher will complain, you can leave it in present and it will still be fairly correct.

All of that gives you...

> Hoy llueve, pero mañana hará/hace sol

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers are okey. I only suggest ommiting "pero": *afortunadamente* performs the function of an adversative.

> Hoy llueve, afortunadamente mañana estará soleado

Answer (score 0):

From [WordReference on *thankfully*](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=thankfully):

> 1. thankfully (with thanks, gratefully) **agradecidamente** adv. *She smiled at us thankfully and said good-bye. Nos sonrió agradecidamente
>      y se despidió.*
> 2. thankfully (fortunately, luckily) **afortunadamente**. **por suerte**.